# Range.Value to Range

Tags: excel, vba, string, range

The address is stored as a string in a worksheet cell. I'm trying to set a new range to the string value of a cell. I keep getting a global error. I've tried several different methods without success. A simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve is below.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
WS.Cells(9,9).Value is ".Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(5,7))"

Dim Rng As Range: Set Rng = Range(WS.Cells(9,9).Value)
```

Comment: your `WS.Cells(9,9).Value` has to be `A1:G7`. Address passed to `Range` in text must be in A1-style. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)#:~:text=If%20you%20use%20a%20text%20argument%20for%20the%20range%20address%2C%20you%20must%20specify%20the%20address%20in%20A1%2Dstyle%20notation%20(you%20cannot%20use%20R1C1%2Dstyle%20notation).)

Comment: I was hoping to pass an R1C1 string. I'll convert it after. Thanks Raymond Wu for your feedback. 

Comment: You cannot execute fragments of VBA at runtime by reading them from a cell of other place (file, etc).

Comment: Building on Raymond's and Tim's comments: you'll have to store _just_ the range reference in the cell.  It can be stored as R1C1, and converted to A1 before use.  See [`Application.ConvertFormula`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.convertformula).  Also consider which workbook/sheet you are referencing